# Is there a way/plugin to draw on a video, like a sports broadcast?

Tags: final-cut-pro

I have Final Cut Pro X, a video of a game and I would like to draw on it. This would be similar to a sports broadcast where circles are drawn around key players and arrows are shown for their movements.

This isn't a live broadcast, so I can cut the video as needed (replays, going back and forth etc.), I just don't want to have to create those lines picture by picture but instead hit record and capture my drawings on it.

I have Motion if it helps.